# Are node x and y automatically set in force layout graphs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [this bl.ocks d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045), how do the nodes get their random "cx" and "cy" attributes? (their x and y positions)? Are they randomly assigned?

The only code I see which assigns nodes' cx and cy is the lines below (at the bottom of the example's code):

```
 node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

However, neither in the data nor anywhere else in the code do I see `d.x` or `d.y` defined. How are they getting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The force layout sets the values. You are connecting the layout to your data here:

```
force
  .nodes(graph.nodes)
  .links(graph.links)
  .start();
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#nodes) (emphasis mine):

> force.nodes([nodes])
>
> If nodes is specified, sets the layout's associated nodes to the specified array. If nodes is not specified, returns the current array, which defaults to the empty array. Each node has the following attributes:
>
> - index - the zero-based index of the node within the nodes array.
> - x - the x-coordinate of the current node position.
> - y - the y-coordinate of the current node position.
> - px - the x-coordinate of the previous node position.
> - py - the y-coordinate of the previous node position.
> - fixed - a boolean indicating whether node position is locked.
> - weight - the node weight; the number of associated links.
>
> **These attributes do not need to be set before passing the nodes to the layout; if they are not set, suitable defaults will be initialized by the layout when start is called.** However, be aware that if you are storing other data on your nodes, your data attributes should not conflict with the above properties used by the layout.

Comment: So are "suitable defaults" just random?

Comment: It can be. The position of neighbors is also taken into account: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js#L251-L275